# Reorder data with start and end columns into contiguous sequence

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, sequence

I have a data frame where each row has a start and an end ID:

```
df <- data.frame(start_id = c("130", "100", "150", "120"),
                 end_id = c("150", "180", "100", "130"))

#   start_id end_id
# 1      130    150
# 2      100    180
# 3      150    100
# 4      120    130
```

I want to sort the data so that the 'end_id' in one row becomes the 'start_id' of the next row; start and end IDs should "connect" to form a contiguous chain. A simple visual representation:

```
120 -> 130                       
       130 -> 150                
              150 -> 100
                     100 -> 180
```

Desired reordered data:

```
#   start_id end_id
# 4      120    130
# 1      130    150
# 3      150    100
# 2      100    180
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your data frame to a graph. Use `get_diameter` to get vertex indices of the longest path. Use indices to order original data.

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
df[head(get_diameter(g), -1), ]
#   start_id end_id
# 4      120    130
# 1      130    150
# 3      150    100
# 2      100    180
```

---

Or use a simple loop:

```
# create a vector of row indices 
# get the first start ID, pre-allocate the remaining indices with NA 
ix <- c(which(!df$start_id %in% df$end_id), rep(NA, nrow(df) - 1))

# for each row, check if end ID in one row matches start ID in the next row
for(i in 2:nrow(df)){
  ix[i] <- match(df$end_id[ix[i - 1]], df$start_id)
}

# reorder data
df[ix, ]
```

---

```
get_diameter(g)
# + 5/5 vertices, named, from 8e3b983:
# [1] 120 130 150 100 180

plot(g)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `dplyr` -

```
df %>% 
  arrange(apply(., 1, max))

  start_id end_id
1      120    130
2      130    150
3      150    100
4      100    180
```

In base R -

```
df[order(apply(df, 1, max)), ]

  start_id end_id
4      120    130
1      130    150
3      150    100
2      100    180
```

For alpha-numeric `ids` as per your comment, you can use `parse_number()` from `readr` which is part of `tidyverse` -

```
df %>% 
  arrange(apply(df, 1, function(x) max(parse_number(x))))

# in base R
df[order(apply(df, 1, function(x) max(parse_number(x)))), ]
```

Comment: thanks! what if the ids are not incremental in numerical value, just random but needed for connecting the dots

Comment: @santoku Sorry, I didn't get you? Is this not what you need?

Comment: so if the df is df= data.frame(start_id=c("B130","100","150A","120",'90'),
               end_id=c("150A","180","100","B130",'20'))
how can I parse out b130-150a-100-180 is a continuity?

Comment: use `parse_number()` from `readr()` which is part of `tidyverse` - `df[order(apply(df, 1, function(x) max(parse_number(x)))), ]`

Comment: Sorry the earlier example with number might be misleading. If take this sample instead: df= data.frame(start_id=c("XYZ","BAU","YIO","UIW",'WPO'), end_id=c("BAU","YUP","XYZ","WPO",'NYX')) how can one identify two continuities, one is YIO-XYZ-BAU-YUP and the other is UIW-WPO-NYX

Comment: @santoku I think Henrik's answer might be what you are looking for. Do check it out.